# Comparing negative number with xsl choose

Tags: xslt, comparison

i am trying to do equal comparison of negative number, but i dont see any output. below is the code.

```
<xsl:variable name="OwnershipStatus" select="Veh_Ownsp[Veh_Ownsp_ID=$OwnerData1/Veh_Ownsp_ID]/Ownsp_Cntl_Type_ID"/>
```

Here OwnershipStatus is returnin`enter code here`g -1

```
xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$OwnershipStatus = -1" >
   <xsl:value-of select="Or"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:value-of select="And"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Needs more information. Try to put together a self-contained example that people can execute to experience the problem for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to hardcode 'Or' and 'And' in case of condition getting evaluated to true and false, respectively. Since the values are literal they should be enclosed with single quotes as shown below:

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$OwnershipStatus = -1" >
    <xsl:value-of select="'Or'"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="'And'"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

Comment: Well spotted. You can also do `<xsl:when test="...">Or</xsl:when>`, and `<xsl:otherwise>And</xsl:otherwise>`.